# Calculating Gas Mileage efficiency

Tags: java, variables, math, double

Since premium gasoline is more expensive than regular, I need to calculate gas mileage one must get on premium gasoline to make up the cost differential between that and regular gasoline. This value is represented by the `gasmileageRequired` variable.

**Question:** Am I calculating the `gasmileageRequired` variable correctly?

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GasMileage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Variable declarations
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        NumberFormat numFmt = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
        NumberFormat costFmt = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        double tankSize = 0;
        final double regularCost;
        final double premiumCost;
        double regularGasMileage = 0;


        //User enters gas tank size
        System.out.print("What is the size of your gas tank? (in gallons) ");
        tankSize = scan.nextDouble();

        //User enters price of regular gasoline
        System.out.print("What is the cost of regular gasoline per gallon? (in $) ");
        regularCost = scan.nextDouble();

        //User enters price of premium gasoline
        System.out.print("What is the cost of premium gasoline per gallon? (in $) ");
        premiumCost = scan.nextDouble();

        //User enters cars' gas mileage
        System.out.print("What is your cars' gas mileage on regular gasoline? (miles/gallon) ");
        regularGasMileage = scan.nextDouble();

        //Variable declarations
        double totalregularCost = regularCost * tankSize;
        double totalpremiumCost = premiumCost * tankSize;
        double costDifference = totalpremiumCost - totalregularCost;
        double gasmileageRequired = regularGasMileage + (premiumCost/costDifference);
        scan.close();

        //Begin output
        System.out.println("\nGas tank size: " + tankSize + " gallons");
        System.out.println("\nTotal cost of regular gasoline: " + costFmt.format(totalregularCost) + "\nGas mileage (regular): " + numFmt.format(regularGasMileage) + " miles/gallon");
        System.out.println("\nTotal cost of premium gasoline: " + costFmt.format(totalpremiumCost) + "\nGas mileage required to make up for cost increase: " +
        numFmt.format(gasmileageRequired) + " miles/gallon");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code - where's the actual question?

Comment: Why do you use the `final` keyword?

Comment: The question is at the top of the code? I want to know if I'm calculating the gasmileageRequired variable correctly.

Comment: If you don't know whether your code is wrong or right, this is technically Code Review domain. Stack Overflow is mostly for when you know your program is wrong, or when you don't know how something works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gasmilageRequired is being calculated correctly, yes. It should tell you how many MPG u would need to get in order to make up the price difference.

Comment: Yeah I knew that I was looking for that, I just have been racking my brains not knowing if that gasmileageRequired variable was being calculated correctly.